# How to select QMake TEMPLATE = lib installation directory / folder?

Tags: qmake

How to option QtCreator QMake to select **where to install** TEMPLATE=lib ?

If I use
"TEMPLATE=lib" it installs in undesired (Linux) folder.

Asked Mrs Google, she does not know how to select library installation folder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods I have used.

1. Modify the target.path in the PROJECT_NAME.pro file. If you create a library project in Qt Creator then by default the .pro file should have something like:

```
# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

You can replace the `/usr/lib` with any other directory on your system.

2. Use the INSTALL_ROOT environmental variable the set the "root" to a different directory. For example, if `INSTALL_ROOT=/home/user/deploy` (and in the .pro file there is still `target.path = /usr/lib`) then `make install` will deploy the result to `/home/user/deploy/usr/lib`.

Note you can set environmental variables in Qt Creator Project mode under the Build Environment settings.