# qmake installs project in /opt instead of /usr/local

Tags: ubuntu, qt5, qmake

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. I have a project which I build from the command line:

```
qmake -qt=qt5
make
sudo make install
```

I expect it to install it in /usr/local/bin, but it puts it in `/opt/QFtpServer/bin/`:

```
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -install qinstall -exe QFtpServer /opt/QFtpServer/bin/QFtpServer
```

I tried `PREFIX=/usr/local sudo make install` but it didn't affect it at all.

I then tried `sudo make install INSTALL_ROOT='/usr/local'` it has effect but it still installed it in the wrong path - `/usr/local/opt/QFtpServer/bin/QFtpServer` instead of `/usr/local/bin/QFtpServer`.

```
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -install qinstall -exe QFtpServer /usr/local/opt/QFtpServer/bin/QFtpServer
```

So how do I get qmake to actually install the thing where I want it to?
My ideal solution is an environment variable that can be set at the time of `sudo make install` - this is the most flexible. I hope I don't have to edit .pri files or set something at the time I first build the project.

Hopefully something as simple as setting the install root is configurable at the time of actual installation, without requiring a rebuild.

Comment: Check your .pro file, maybe you have there something like `target.path = /opt`. Set it to just `/` (root) and then you can use INSTALL_ROOT env var to install it anywhere. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78098000/2355028

Comment: Can you show the project file? I think it might help the discussion.